# How to hide a specific actor in python-vtk

Tags: vtk

There are some actors in same scene, I need to hide an actor of specific index (Not remove it, just hide). Maybe There are some API in python-vtk, but i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide an actor:

```
actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0)
```

[Here](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProperty.html#details) is the vtkProperty API (c++ but Python is quite the same)

#### *edit*

Or as @mmusy suggest, simply

```
actor.VisibilityOff()
```

[actor API](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProp.html#a41c22a68b45cf9be5fb1bb1dbca41277).

Comment: Is it the same as `actor.VisibilityOff()` ?

Comment: Hi, I'm new in vtk, Could you tell me how to implement it in Python-VTK code(not c++). There are four actors in a scene. I need to hide the third one. First, maybe I need to find its index, and then how to hide the actor corresponding to its index. Thank you for kind help!

Comment: it seems to be a larger question. Please create a new post with some code for the context (code you have, may code you tried etc). And do not forget to check the [examples](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a specific actor, you should be able to first select it. Actors in vtk is not indexed. So what you can do is, create a vtkActorCollection [https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkActorCollection.html].

```
`ActorCollection=vtk.vtkActorCollection()`
```

Now add your actors to the collection by,

```
ActorCollection.AddItem(actor)
```

Each actor now hold an index in the collection. You can get the actor by calling

```
select_actor = ActorCollection.GetItemAsObject(i)
```

Where i is the index of the item.

Change the visibility of the selected actor by

```
select_actor.VisibilityOff()
```